# Changing the font of greek letters of mathastext

Tags: fonts, mathastext

I'm using the `mathastext` package to make math contents consist with the text. The package offers a `\MTgreekfont` command to change the font of greek letters. Current I use the `lmtt` font but its size does not match that of Courier, thus I would like to switch to the one native to Courier. However I cannot find the internal name of Courier (like `lmtt` for Latin Modern), `\MTgreekfont{courier}` does not work. How can I find this internal name? Or, is there a way to change the scale of current greek letters?

Moreover, what if I use Menlo font with xelatex? The font itself apparently offers greek letters, How could I use them with `mathastext`?

Below is a MWE.

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courierten}% Courier
% \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}% These two lines require xelatex
% \setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Menlo}% Menlo
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\usepackage[italic,LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\MTgreekfont{lmtt} % What should I put here respectively, for Courier and Menlo?
\Mathastext
\begin{document}
\noindent Text\\
$\alpha\beta\gamma\epsilon$
\end{document}
```

Comment: looking at the fd files seems to be `CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF`

Comment: ... but that font has no Greek `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'LGR/CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF/m/it' undefined`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I chose `courierten` for pdflatex, but in practice I use `\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier}` with xelatex, which I think contains Greek letters.

Comment: sure but a Unicode Opentype font used by xelatex can have tens of thousands of characters, but a font used by pdflatex can have at most 256 so something has to go, the font maintainer can choose different subsets to make into pdftex compatible fonts the T1 encoding you have specified (and is supported by `courier10`) has 256 accented _latin_ script characters and no Greek. It would be possible to subset the original font again to make a subset matching the Greek LGR pdftex encoding but that hasn't been done so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are:

- Load an OpenType math font with `unicode-math`, in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  All of them come with Greek alphabets. You can change its Greek alphabet with `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=it/{Greek,greek}]{Some Greek Italic Font}`, etc.
- Load `\setmathsfont(Greek}` in `mathspec` in XeTeX.
- Load a legacy 8-bit font in the LGR encoding, using `mathastext`. You generally want to look for a file named `lgr*.fd`.  if you don’t care about keeping the fixed width, you might pair the Greek Font Society’s GFS Neohellenic.
- Load `\usepackage{gfsneohellenicot}` in PDFTeX to get GFS Neohellenic Math, then use `\usepackage{mathastext}` to change the Latin letters to Courier/Cursor.
- Load a legacy OML math font, containing both Greek and Latin letters, with `isomath` or `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.

Answer (score 4):

Solution, using `pdflatex` and `mathastext`. On my Linux system with `texlive`, I found the `LGR` font files with the command `find texlive -name "*LGR*fd"` (`texlive` is in my home directory), and then one can find the font names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{courierten} % CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF
\usepackage[italic,LGRgreek]{mathastext}

\newcommand{\mtset}[1]{\MTfamily{#1}\MTgreekfont{#1}\Mathastext[#1]}
\mtset{Cochineal-TLF}
\mtset{CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF}
\mtset{DejaVuSans-TLF}
\mtset{EBGaramond-TLF}
\mtset{TheanoDidot-TLF}
\mtset{TheanoOldStyle-TLF}
\mtset{lmtt}

% Switches font
\newcommand{\mtv}{\MTversion}
% Creates row in tabular
\newcommand{\mtrow}[1]{\mtv{#1} #1:
  &\quad\mtv{#1}$\alpha$&\mtv{#1}$\beta$&\mtv{#1}$\gamma$&\mtv{#1}$\delta$
  &\mtv{#1}$\epsilon$&\mtv{#1}$\zeta$&\mtv{#1}$\eta$&\mtv{#1}$\theta$
  &\mtv{#1}$\iota$&\mtv{#1}$\kappa$&\mtv{#1}$\lambda$&\mtv{#1}$\mu$
  &\mtv{#1}$\nu$&\mtv{#1}$\xi$&\mtv{#1}$\pi$&\mtv{#1}$\rho$
  &\mtv{#1}$\sigma$&\mtv{#1}$\tau$&\mtv{#1}$\upsilon$&\mtv{#1}$\phi$
  &\mtv{#1}$\chi$&\mtv{#1}$\psi$&\mtv{#1}$\omega$\\[2mm]
}

\begin{document}


\mtv{CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF} CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF is default
tt-font in the question's setup but it has no greek alphabet\medskip
  
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{rccccccccccccccccccccccc}
  \hline\\
  \mtrow{Cochineal-TLF}
  \mtrow{CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF}
  \mtrow{DejaVuSans-TLF}
  \mtrow{EBGaramond-TLF}
  \mtrow{TheanoDidot-TLF}
  \mtrow{TheanoOldStyle-TLF}
  \mtrow{lmtt}
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip

\mtv{CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF} A little courier with its math
$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$

\mtv{CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF} A little courier \MTversion*{lmtt} with
lmtt's math $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$

\mtv{lmtt} A little lmtt with its math
$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)dx $
\end{document}
```

[image: small sample]

Many interesting and beautiful  greek fonts that I could find in `texlive` on my system.

[image: many greek fonts]

Comment: there are also some with lowercase lgr such as `tempora-TLF` and others

Comment: @user691586 you were right, so I added some more, including some funky ones like `fmm` and `solomos`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using XeLaTeX, you can declare the Greek letters to use the main font (assuming it contains them).

```
documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}% These two lines require xelatex
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\setmonofont{Menlo}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}

\Mathastext

\Umathchardef\alpha="0 \symmtletterfont `α
\Umathchardef\beta="0 \symmtletterfont `β
\Umathchardef\gamma="0 \symmtletterfont `γ
\Umathchardef\epsilon="0 \symmtletterfont `ε

\begin{document}

Text $x\alpha\beta\gamma\epsilon$

\end{document}
```

Fill in the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To address the original problem, perhaps rescaling `courier` will do the job: use `courier` for math but, since it doesn't have its own greek, use `lmtt`'s greek.  In my opinion, `lmtt`'s math looks better than `courier`s because of its use of italics instead of just slanted, so use `courier` with `lmtt` math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scale=0.95]{courierten} % CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF
\usepackage[italic,LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\MTfamily{CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF}
\Mathastext[courier]
\MTfamily{CourierOneZeroPitch-TLF}
\MTgreekfont{lmtt}
\Mathastext[courierlmtt]
\MTfamily{lmtt}
\MTgreekfont{lmtt}
\Mathastext[lmtt]

% Switches font
\newcommand{\mtv}{\MTversion}

\begin{document}
\mtv{courier} Here is a \emph{\textbf{little courier}} with its math
but doesn't have its own greek so I think it gets cmr's
$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}{2}\int_0^1
f(x)dx$.\bigskip

\mtv{courierlmtt} Here is a \textbf{\emph{little courier}} with lmtt's
greek $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}{2}\int_0^1
f(x)dx$. \bigskip

\mtv{lmtt} Here is a \emph{\textbf{little pure lmtt}} with it own math
$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.\bigskip 

\mtv{courier}\mtv*{lmtt} Here is a \textbf{\emph{little courier}} with
lmtt math
$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.
\end{document}
```

[image: lmtt courier mix]