# Does a cursive script math font exist for uppercase Greek letters?

Tags: greek, math-fonts

In LaTeX within Overleaf (Tex Live version 2022), I am using primarily `\mathrsfso{}` (in KaTeX I use `\mathscr`) to get a cursive script uppercase letter math font. These are often used in mathematics and in particular measure theory for representing the sets for spaces. I use the font styling to indicate this consistent meaning.

The following is the "cusrive script" font I am talking about where `mathrsfs` is the required package.
[image: mathscr{ABC} required package mathrsfs]

I would like to also be able to use Greek uppercase letters in a similar cursive script math font, however `\mathrsfso` does not support them and after searching I have yet to find such a font.

**Does a cursive script math font exist for uppercase Greek letters?**

Ideally, the font would also include lowercase letters for more coverage than just the `\vartheta` and other var subset of lowercase Greek letters.

Example of cursive script uppercase and lowercase letters that I'm looking for in a font.
[image]

---

Related question, but without any cursive capital letters: [A Whole List of Math Fonts for Greek Letters in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/487710/125912)

I'm working through some from below, but no luck so far.

CTAN's topic for fonts that support typesetting Greek: https://www.ctan.org/topic/greek

Calligraphic and Handwritten font in the LaTeX Font Catalogue, though seems no uppercase Greek: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4):

I did more searching and I found a couple of somewhat calligraphic Greek fonts with uppercase Greek from this list: https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-greek

The list is for Greek fonts in general, not math fonts, and so some extra (cursed) work is required to use them as a one off command, such as `$\greekscr{\Gamma \Pi \Theta \Psi \Phi}$`.

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487838/125912) linked to the Greek font list I used and mentioned using [mathastext](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) on LGR-encoded Greek fonts. mathastext also mentioned [lgrmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lgrmath), which is an option supposed to be for a global single change to your default math font, rather than swapping "Math Versions" throughout the document as mathastext enables.

### Miama (Nueva) : referenced in code as `fmm`

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/miama

Calligraphic or handwritten script with Greek uppercase and lowercase letters. It is not as visually busy as the calligraphic style of `mathscr` from `mathrsfs`.
[image: miama nueva Greek uppercase and lowercase]
[image: table of miama math letter to symbol]

To get miama to work in my case I had to use both mathastext and lgrmath, because using mathastext alone did not work and I have no idea why. So here is my cursed hack that worked. I put the following in my preamble prior to `\document` and swapped Overleaf compiler to LuaLaTeX, which is required for `lgrmath` otherwise XeLaTex.

```
% Following 3 are unnecessary, but useful to know
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} %fontspec for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
%\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

% scaled down to match size of other fonts.
\usepackage[scale=.75]{miama}

\usepackage[subdued, LGRgreek, italic]{mathastext}
\MTDeclareVersion{greekfont}{T1}{fmm}{it}{sl}
\newcommand{\greekscr}[1]{\Mathastextversion{greekfont} #1 \Mathastextversion{normal}}
% This has to come after mathastext, and yes, this is hacky.
\usepackage[font=fmm, alphabets]{lgrmath}
```

Calling `$\greekscr{\Psi}$` now provides Greek script upper or lowercase. I noticed the lowercase letters are a bit smaller in scale than the uppercase.

If you use a local version with TexLive, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711660/125912) claims it works with mathastext alone and pdflatex compiler.

### Talos

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/talos

More like `mathcal` than cursive calligraphic or handwritten script, however rare enough to be worth sharing if someone prefers this style.

[image: talos example of uppercase italic Greek]
[image: talos example of lowercase italic Greek]

I have yet to get this font to work in my Overleaf project. Probably due to [fontsetup](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontsetup) colliding with the namespaces of other font packages I have installed. It also requires LuaLaTex or XeLaTex compilers and is installed with `\usepackage[talos]{fontsetup}`

Comment: NVM. I thought I got `\greekscr{}` to only affect the encapsulated math characters, but apparently not, when looking throughout my document more. ATM I don't have a working solution with `mathastext` using these fonts in Overleaf. Also these fonts aren't styled as much as `mathscr` capital letters are. Seems the font doesn't exist atm.